# Unexpected token error when connecting to MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, token

I am trying to connect to a MYSQL database with PHP. I keep getting two errors no matter what I try:

SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token A"}

AND

SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token N"}

The following is the current code I have:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 8889;
    $username = "********"; 
    $password = "********";   
    $database="***datebasename***";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    if (!$server) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['type'];
    } else {
        $type = "null";
        echo "Type not passed";
    }

    if($type=='load'){
        $string = '';
        $gene = $_GET["gene"];
        $data = $_GET["data"];

        $myquery = "select gene_data.gene_data from genes inner join gene_data on genes.id=gene_data.g_id where genes.name ='$gene' and genes.type='$data'";
        $query = mysql_query($myquery);

        if ( !$myquery ) {
            echo mysql_error();
            die;
        }

        if ( !$query ) {
            echo mysql_error();
            die;
        }


        $data = array();
        for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
            $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
        mysql_close($server);
    }
?>
```

Of course I have realistic strings for my username, password and database name.

Comment: Does it say what line that error is on?

Comment: What are the values for `$gene` and `$data`? It could be a SQL injection problem.

Comment: Do not write new code using the `mysql_*` functions. They are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future PHP versions. Use `msqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider When I use msqli I get Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: @JonSturdevant They are 2 strings. And I'm sure it's not an injection problem. I've tried using a quesry as simple as "select * from genes;"

Comment: @JohnConde No, the error is returned to the caller, which is D3.js in my case. And apparently can't interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined $username but you use $user in the mysql_connect function.

The correct using the fetch assoc for example:

```
<code>

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["userid"];
        echo $row["fullname"];
        echo $row["userstatus"];
    }

</code>
```

And I think you should forget these functions and maybe you can use the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Very nicely spotted. Thank you very much, that solved my problem!

Comment: I tried re-writing my entire php file to use PDO instead, can you explain how I perform the last 5 lines of my code using PDO please? I seem to be a little confused about it.

Comment: Ok. I have not enough time to explain it to you but maybe you can use this:
self::$statement = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
self::$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
self::$statement->execute();

Answer (score 1):

You have `echo` statements in your code (in particular, `echo mysql_error()` appears a few times). If any of these errors are output, your result looks something like:

```
An error occurred[{"id":"1","name":"test"}]
```

In other words, you have your error message followed by the actual JSON.

When your browser tries to parse this, that first character is unexpected, therefore causing it to throw `Unexpected token A` in the example above.

Check the Network tab of your Developer Tools to see exactly what your browser is sending back, you almost certainly have some kind of error being shown.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I checked the network tab and it says everything is okay. Here's a link to a screenshot of the status:
http://puu.sh/7QJsb.png

Comment: @Vanquiza this is not what Niet meant. click on the entry to see the actual content of the server response.